# How to remove fading and sliding effects from Firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox, desktop

Are there ways to remove the sliding and fading effects from Firefox as an end user when I visit web pages that use such javascript effects?

When some element is inserted into the DOM, the elements after it are slided down. This is a graphical effect, that is very time and bandwith consuming when someone is viewing over a remote connection (terminal server, citrix, remote X, nx) It would just be OK to see the page in it's new shape without the sliding and many intermediate states.

Maybe there is a setting for this already (about:config)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [greasemonkey scripts](http://userscripts.org) for most popular sites to streamline the interface and eliminate such annoyances.  There is no way to disable it in general because it is not a single feature but an emergent result of a combination of otherwise benign features.

To clarify that last bit... Each individual javascript function used for these animations (that is, timers and element size/placement manipulation) has legitimate uses.  It is only the combination of them that is a problem, and they can be combined with other operations in myriad ways.  Some sort of heuristic could possibly identify likely-annoying animations in websites at large, but individual fixes targeting specific sites (or site frameworks, all jquery sites use the same animation code, etc) will be far more effective and efficient.

Comment: The effect consumes plenty of bandwidth if the browser is running remotely, and the user is interacting with it over X or Citrix or VNC, etc!

Comment: I mostly use VNC for remote access, which uses tile caching so that this sort of effect doesn't consume extra bandwidth.  I naively assumed the other remote tools you mentioned probably had similar functionality.

Comment: You said "an emergent result of a combination of otherwise benign features" - can you go into detail?

Comment: Those kind of sliding effects are quick changes in the document structure, like a transparency value, or position, and really a lot of them. Those are good for sure, but the combination of a lot of them in a quick pace makes the an undesirable effect to 'emerge' from the desirable effects. But the solution here is either improving the visualization protocol, or drop scripts, or fall down to CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into the NoScript extension for firefox- it will disable all javascript on every site, and can then be turned on for a site-by-site basis.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722

Comment: Thank you, this would work. Anyway it is not what I wanted. I am not trying to turn off javascript. Just change the behaviour of firefox directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension:

[Disable Transitions and Animations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/no-transition/?src=search)

> Today when you open a menu it often "slide" for 0.2 second or links
>   change color by a slow fading... Those effect are made with CSS3
>   animations/transition and can be heavy or reduce the website
>   accessibility. With this extension transition are instantaneous.